# Mahout K-Means - Getting the Mean Square Error?

Tags: mapreduce, cluster-computing, mahout, k-means, mse

I have been trying to check the quality of the clusters in Mahout K-Means and I was wondering if it is possible to get the Mean Square Error from the clusterDumper or using another command in mahout?

With ClusterDumper I was only able to get the points assigned to each clusters, the cluster values and the radius values but not the Within cluster sum of squared errors (MSE).
http://mahout.apache.org/users/clustering/cluster-dumper.html